# Correlation on array or a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, correlation

What would be best and better option?

using a correlation method (.corr()) on a DataFrame or an array?
I know we can use .corr() method on a DataFrame, but what about with an array? Is it possible?

The reason I am doing this is because I want to see if the correlations between different variables would change after implementing StandardScaler() on the dataset ; that is, to bring down variables and/or features on the same scale level.

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know we can use .corr() method on a DataFrame, but what about with
> an array? Is it possible?

Yes, the function that you are looking for is numpy's `corrcoef`.

Let us consider this example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
...     'name': ['Hildegarde', 'Buba', 'Virginie', 'Eustache', 'Robin', 'Nasredine', 'Maurice'],
...     'age': [41, 28, 35, 44, 55, 11, 37],
...     'score': [88.0, 59.0, 81.0, 50.0, 58.0, 61.0, 84.0]
... }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
array1 = df['age'].to_numpy()
array2 = df['score'].to_numpy()
```

`df.corr('pearson')` returns:

```
        age         score 
age     1.000000    0.013343 
score   0.013343    1.000000
```

`np.corrcoef(array1, array2)` returns an array containing the same values:

```
array([[1.        , 0.01334299],
       [0.01334299, 1.        ]])
```

If your input data are stored in a pandas dataframe, then I would stick to pandas' `corr()` function to avoid unnecessary manipulations. In addition, `corr()` allows you to experiment with other methods of correlation (*e.g.* `kendall`), while `corrcoef` is limited to Pearon's correlation.

**EDIT:** To convince yourself that the standard scaler does not affect your correlation coefficient, you may check [this demonstration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220738/363918) on stats Stack Exchange or try it for yourself by running:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
std_scaler = StandardScaler()
df_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(df[['age','score']].to_numpy())
np.corrcoef(df_scaled[:,0], df_scaled[:,1])
```

Which returns:

```
array([[1.        , 0.01334299],
       [0.01334299, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So from your answer, I guess using StandardScaler() method wouldn't change much with the correlations regardless if dataframe or array. @Shleldon

Comment: Applying the standard scaler does not affect the correlation coefficient, regardless of whether you compute this coefficient using pandas or numpy. I edited my answer to provide you with an example.